# Ansible module error when using it with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

I upgraded `Ansible core` from `2.3.2` to `2.4` and understand that **managed nodes** require `Python 2.6` Installed. Most of our servers are running lower version of Python i.e. `2.5.x or 2.4.x`, hence, I thought to compile and install `Python 2.7.14` (tried higher version as well) in `/usr/bin/python27/` directory.

Now whenever I use `ansible_python_interpreter=<path to python27 here>`, i get **`module failure`** errors. Not sure what to do here. Any suggestions? Not even a single module works

```
[root@ansserver ~]# ansible -m ping ansclient -e 'ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python27/bin/python2.7"'

ansclient | FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"module_stderr": "Shared connection to ansclient closed.\r\n",
"module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522952509.97-245603241066270/ping.py\", line 123, in <module>\r\n    f.write(z.read('ansible_module_ping.py'))\r\n  File \"/usr/bin/python27/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 935, in read\r\n    return self.open(name, \"r\", pwd).read()\r\n  File \"/usr/bin/python27/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 1010, in open\r\n    close_fileobj=should_close)\r\n  File \"/usr/bin/python27/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 526, in __init__\r\n    self._decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-15)\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompressobj'\r\n",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
"rc": 0
```

is it something to do with **Ansible** or **Python** itself? Thank you.

Comment: Check that `zlib` is available in Python on target host.

Comment: `zlib` is installed on both server and client `[root@ansclient python27]# rpm -qa | grep zlib
zlib-1.2.3-7.el5
zlib-devel-1.2.3-7.el5
zlib-1.2.3-7.el5
zlib-devel-1.2.3-7.el5
`

Comment: You should check it from inside python

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by installing `zlib-devel` in the system and then Compiling the `python` after. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164567/246082) thread was helpful.